# How to change a meta value (of a published post) after X days.?

Tags: functions, wp-admin, metabox, date-time

I have a custom field. I would like to change the text of that custom field after x days.

I want something like this:

```
if ( published post is more than 90 days old ) {
    echo "your post is more than 90 days old"; 
}
else {
    echo "your post is less than 90 days old";
}
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a meta field for this logic.

In the loop `$post->post_date` holds when the post is published. From there you can determine if the date is 90 days old:

```
$datetime = strtotime($post->post_date);
if( $datetime < ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 ) ) ) {
    echo "> 90 days old"
} else {
    echo "< 90 days old"
}
```

Comment: ROFL at the `MR`.Brady. Inside joke.